# How to get total RAM from Golang code on Mac?

Tags: macos, go, sysinfo

I have some Linux code in golang:

```
import "syscall"

var info syscall.Sysinfo_t
err := syscall.Sysinfo(&info)
totalRam := info.Totalram
```

I'd like to port this to Mac OS X.
I see that Sysinfo is available on Linux but not on Mac:

Linux:

```
$ go list -f '{{.GoFiles}}' syscall | sed -e "s/[][]//g" | xargs fgrep --color -Iwn Sysinfo
syscall_linux.go:962://sysnb    Sysinfo(info *Sysinfo_t) (err error)
zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:822:func Sysinfo(info *Sysinfo_t) (err error) {\
```

Mac:

```
$ go list -f '{{.GoFiles}}' syscall | sed -e "s/[][]//g" | xargs fgrep --color -Iwn Sysinfo
# No results
```

What is the correct way to get the system RAM info on Mac?

Comment: Could you take a look if this fits you? https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#ReadMemStats

Comment: Forgive my previous question, here is a package that is currently supported for cross-platform. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pbnjay/memory

Example usage would be `fmt.Printf("Total system memory: %d\n", memory.TotalMemory())`

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted if you find it useful?

Answer (score 5):

This code is cross-compile supported.

**Pre-requisites**:

> Get this package [github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem"
)

func errHandler(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func main() {
    runtimeOS := runtime.GOOS
    runtimeARCH := runtime.GOARCH
    fmt.Println("OS: ", runtimeOS)
    fmt.Println("Architecture: ", runtimeARCH)
    vmStat, err := mem.VirtualMemory()
    errHandler(err)
    fmt.Println("Total memory: ", strconv.FormatUint(vmStat.Total/(1024*1024), 10)+" MB")
    fmt.Println("Free memory: ", strconv.FormatUint(vmStat.Free/(1024*1024), 10)+" MB")

    // Cached and swap memory are ignored. Should be considered to get the understanding of the used %
    fmt.Println("Percentage used memory: ", strconv.FormatFloat(vmStat.UsedPercent, 'f', 2, 64)+"%")
}
```